# "Stare in gamba" può significare comportarsi bene?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

Nel film *Sciuscià*, diretto da Vittorio de Sica, c'è una scena nella quale i due ragazzi protagonisti, Pasquale e Giuseppe, quando sono in carcere, stanno per azzuffarsi: Giuseppe accusa Pasquale di essere una spia. Una rissa sta per scoppiare tra i ragazzi del carcere quando appare un custode che dice "State in gamba, ragazzi!" e finalmente tutto si calma.

Sto cercando di capire il significato di questa frase detta dal custode. Ho cercato il significato di "stare in gamba" sul [dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/G/gamba.shtml#21) e anche sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gamba/), ma le definizioni che ho trovato sembrano fare riferimento alla salute, cosa che non ha senso in questo contesto. La mia domanda è: il modo di dire "stare in gamba" può significare comportarsi bene? Se no è così, qual è il suo significato in questo contesto?

Answer (score 2):

Da Treccani.it

***Gamba***:

> - anche come raccomandazione, ***sta’ in gamba!, sta’ attento!, bada a te stesso!***

Il custode sta avvertendo i ragazzi di stare attenti a non incorrere in eventuali punizioni.

Comment: Avevo già letto questo nel Treccani. Comunque, dalla spiegazione completa [*stare (bene) in gamba*, meno com. *in gambe*, esser forte, in buona salute (anche come raccomandazione, *sta’ in gamba!*, sta’ attento!, bada a te stesso!)] ho interpretato che quel *sta’ in gamba!* si riferisse a stare attento o badare alla propria salute.

Comment: @Charo - capisco  I il fraintendimento, ma non avrebbe molto senso nel contesto di  due ragazzi che stanno litigando in un carcere.